# What is the efficient method to compare files list in Client and remote Server

Tags: c++, c

I have the below situation which need to be addressed efficiently,

I'm doing file sync from client devices to server. Sometimes what happen is file from one device doesn't get fetched to another device from the server due to some issues with server. I need to make sure that all the files in the server are synced to all the client devices using a separate thread. I am using C++ for the development and libcurl for client to server communication.

Here in the client device, we have an entry for downloaded files in the SQLite Database. Likewise in the server, we have similar updates in the server databases (MySQL) too. I need to list all the available files from the client device and send it to server and have to compare it with the list taken from the server database to find out the missed files.

I did a rough estimation that for 1 million files list (File Name with Full Path), it is about 85 MB in size. Upon compression it goes upto 10 MB in size. So transferring this entire file list (even after compression) from client to server is not a good idea. I planned to implement Bloom Filters for this as below,

1. Fetch files list from client side database and convert those to Bloom Filter Data Structure.
2. Just transferring the bloom data structure alone from client to the server.
3. Fetch files list from server side database and compare it with Bloom data structure received from the client and find out the missing files.

Please note that the above process initiated from client should be handled in thread at regular interval say for every 1 hour or so.

The problem with Bloom filters is false positive rates even if it very low. I don't want to miss out even a single file. Is there any other better way of doing this ?.

Comment: I would do something similar to [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm). Or, even just use `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know rsync algorithm which is useful for sending only changed block to remote server thereby reducing the bandwidth usage. Even I have used this librsync for sending only modified file contents to the server. Can you tell me how to use rsync to address my problem mentioned above ?

Comment: "So transferring this entire file list (even after compression) from client to server is not a good idea". Hmmm. transfer only *changed* data in the file list.. Now what would be good for that...? Perhaps.. `rsync`?

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks for your comments. The only problem I see here is we need to save the list file in server again which would add up to the disk space. Assume every client device sends the files list using rsync to server. But server has to apply patch to get the actual files list and then have to compare it with server list. If we have 10 client devices synced to the common server, we need to save the file content of all the relavent devices which costs more disk space which mostly customers wont agree.

Comment: I see. Still, for a million files, an 85MB index is certainly within reason, though if it were being managed as you say I'd keep a lot more data in it than just the names and paths. I think caf has some interesting ideas on this, btw.

Comment: Yes 85MB per device only. So it would add up depending on the number of client devices synced to the server. Assuming 10 clients each with 1 million files (with 85 MB in size), it would cost 850MB and comparison gets slower if disk I/O performance is very slow or heavily fragmented. Yes I am checking the one suggested by caf.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, this isn't a problem for which Bloom Filters are appropriate.  With a Bloom Filter, when you get a hit you must then check the authoritative source to differentiate between a false positive and a true positive - they're useful in situations where most queries against the filter will be expected to give a *negative* result, which is the opposite to your case.

What you could do is have each side build a partial Prefix Tree in memory of all the filenames known to that side.  It wouldn't be a full prefix tree - once you number of filenames below a node drops below a certain level you'd just include the full list of those filenames in that node.  You then synchronise those prefix trees using a recursive algorithm starting at the root of the trees:

1. Each side creates a hash of all the sorted, concatenated filenames below the current node.
2. If the hashes are equal then this node and all descendents are synchronised - return.
3. If there are no child nodes, send the (short) list of filenames at this terminal node from one side to the other to synchronise and return.
4. Otherwise, recursively synchronise the child nodes and return.

The hash should be at least 128 bits, and make sure that when you concatenate the filenames for the hash you do so in a reversible manner (ie. seperate them with a character that can't appear in filenames like `\0`, or prefix each one with its length).

Comment: As you said, with Bloom Filters I need to do extra check to differentiate true positive and false positive. I am still not very clear about Suffix Tree implementation. Can you point me some examples on this ? Also tell me how would be the size of Suffix Tree implemenation ?

Comment: That is exactly the spirit of what I would have suggested. I also would have handled the files and the folders differently under a node, and grouped the entries (say by alphabetical order, "a" to (number_of_entries/10) etc) in order to isolate the differences more precisely. Just in case the number of entries in directories were unbalanced.

Comment: @Prabu: Sorry, I made a mistake - I meant Prefix Tree.  It's a standard data structure with plenty of information available on it out there.  The amount of data transferred with this implementation would be dependent on how many files were missing on the client - in the best case with none missing, it would only need to transfer a single hash value.

Comment: @Raffi: Right, you can be clever in the manner that you create the tree (for example by allowing the edges to have variable-length prefixes depending on the number of descendants).

Comment: @caf, Yeah I'm checking prefix tree after googling. Thanks for your method.

Comment: @caf, I would appreciate if you could see my post below in this thread and clear the things related to prefix hash tree implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In file/pathname compression I've found a prefix-suffix compression to work better even alone than a generic (bz2) compression. When combined, the filename list could be reduced even more.

The trick is in using escape codes (e.g. <32) to indicate the number of common characters to the previous row, then use regular characters for the unique part and finally (optionally) encode the number of common characters at the end of the string.

Comment: I will check for this. Btw can you point me some url or examples on this.

Comment: Seems to depend on the data. Just compressed my linux file structure (85000 files) with 'prefix-only' compression -- just 1 extra character in front of every line... so it's reversible without any fancy escape codes: 5Mb file compresses to 200kb, when tar.bz2 takes 340kb. In that data the suffix compression didn't work as planned.